# how to insert the database multiple gridview choises

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datagridview

```
  siparisDetayy order = new siparisDetayy();
    public void gridControl()
    {       
        for (int i = 0; i < dtGridSiparis.RowCount-1; i++)
            {
            order.productID =(dtGridSiparis.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value).ToString();
            order.productName = dtGridSiparis.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            order.customer = dtGridSiparis.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            order.faturaNo = dtGridSiparis.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            order.miktar = dtGridSiparis.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            order.price = dtGridSiparis.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            }
            ctx.siparisDetayys.InsertOnSubmit(order);
            ctx.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

> I try to insert all of data my databese by using LINQ, even though I did for loop but still only one row adding.

Comment: i'm clearly seeing that you're inserting only a single object, try a collection of object then insert them all using a loop/linq or whatever.

Comment: `order.price` is string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Rahul said, but also add the first line "siparisDetayy order = new siparisDetayy();" inside the loop. You have to create a new entity for each row.

Comment: THANK you so much

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's cause you are actually inserting only one `order` record and hopefully the last one you are collecting from loop last iteration. Move the saving to DB code lines inside loop like below

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dtGridSiparis.RowCount-1; i++)
        {
        order.productID =(dtGridSiparis.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value).ToString();
        order.productName = dtGridSiparis.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        order.customer = dtGridSiparis.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        order.faturaNo = dtGridSiparis.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        order.miktar = dtGridSiparis.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        order.price = dtGridSiparis.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();

        //Save or Insert the record to database
        ctx.siparisDetayys.InsertOnSubmit(order);
        ctx.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Yes I'v done but It shows me that  errorMessage: "An entity that already exists can not be added."

Comment: @ZulfikarBakır, yes it will if your grid rows are duplicate since you are not checking for that. Well that's a separate question and thus post it separately.